# Javascript subroutines don't run

Tags: javascript

So I am new to javascript and a beginner programmer. I know the initialization subroutine always go first. I don't get why the subroutines aren't running. And I was wondering if any variables in the initialization subroutine can be used in any other subroutines. I am trying to make a program using Bresenham Line Algorithm.

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;" onclick="coordinates(event)">></canvas>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      intialization();
      drawGrid();
      mouseClick();
      //Intialization--------------------------------
      //Intialization--------------------------------
      function intialization() {
        var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var Width = cnv.width;
        var Height = cnv.height;
        var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
        var click_counter = 0; //switching between storing first and second point coordinates
        p1x = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
        p1y = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
        p2x = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
        p2y = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
      }
      //Intialization--------------------------------
      //GRID---------------------------------
      function drawGrid() {
        var gridLines = {
          Lines: {
            space: 10,
            // color: "'#xxxxxx'"
          }
        };
        drawGridLines(cnv, gridLines.Lines);
        return;
      }

      function drawGridLines(cnv, lineOptions) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = lineOptions.color;
        ctx.strokeWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        var counter = null;
        var i = null;
        var x = null;
        var y = null;
        counter = Math.floor(Width / lineOptions.space);
        for (i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
          x = (i * lineOptions.space);
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, Height);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        counter = Math.floor(Height / lineOptions.space);
        for (i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
          y = (i * lineOptions.space);
          ctx.moveTo(0, y);
          ctx.lineTo(Width, y);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        return;
      }
      //GRID---------------------------------
      //MOUSE---------------------------------
      function mouseClick {
        if (click_counter = 0) {
          function coordinates(event) {
            var x1 = event.offsetX;
            var y1 = event.offsetY;
            p1x = x1;
            p1y = y1;
            console.log("x coords: " + p1x + ", y coords: " + p1y);
          } else

          function coordinates(event) {
            var x1 = event.offsetX;
            var y1 = event.offsetY;
            p2x = x1;
            p2y = y1;
            console.log("x coords: " + p2x + ", y coords: " + p2y);
          }
        }
        //MOUSE---------------------------------
        //MOUSE---------------------------------

    </script>

  </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because of that syntax error you're getting? Try fixing that first.

Comment: Yeah, at the very least I see a missing close-bracket at the end-- I think there might be more issues than that.  Maybe try using a linter.

Comment: Any free IDE, I can use to check for syntax errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization and drawGrid functions are being called before the document is even loaded so this will fail. You should use the jquery method-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
             //callyour functions here
    })
```

Another issue you have is that you are trying to use variables which are out of scope. Like `cnv` for example. You should declare a object like canvas at the top of your js:

```
canvas = {}
```

and add all of the variables you want to share to this. for instance :

```
canvas.cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.Width = canvas.cnv.width;
canvas.Height = canvas.cnv.height;
canvas.ctx = canvas.cnv.getContext('2d');
```

Here is a simple example of how to use the canvas:

```
<html>

  <head>

      <script src="index.js"></script>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;" onmousemove="mouseClick(event)">></canvas>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
         canvas = {}
         var isMouseDown = false;

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
            if ( event.which ) isMouseDown = true;
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
            if ( event.which ) isMouseDown = false;
        }, true);


        $(document).ready(function(){
        canvas.cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.Width = canvas.cnv.width;
        canvas.Height = canvas.cnv.height;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.cnv.getContext('2d');
        });


        function mouseClick(e) {
            console.log(isMouseDown)
            if (isMouseDown){
            var x1 = event.offsetX;
            var y1 = event.offsetY;

            canvas.ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
            canvas.ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
</script>

  </head>

</html>
```

Comment: So I added the document ready function. I declare canvas in the body brackets at the very top. Am I suppose to declare canvas in the script brackets?

 `code` <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        intialization();
        drawGrid();
        mouseClick();
      })`code`

Comment: No the canvas you declared is an html object. Its only accessible via a dom query like  canvas.cnv = document.getElementById("canvas"). I think what you want is to retrieve properties of the canvas once its loaded to the screen. So the best implementation for this would be to have a global object.

Comment: I declared `code`var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");`code` in the initialization subroutine. Is that different than canvas.cnv = document.getElementById("canvas"); ?

https://jsfiddle.net/Dinomite07/drzynm96/57/

Comment: Yes because if you notice im declaring 'canvas' outside of the function. So this makes that object accessible to all functions. Where as your cnv will be lost once you exit the initialization function (along with Width, Height and ctx).

Comment: so all my variables in the document ready function will be accessible to any function. the drawGrid function should run and then exit out. And the mouse event continually runs. 
I looked through the code line by and line and it looks fine but i know i did something wrong. im not sure whats wrong and i dont know how to debug it


https://jsfiddle.net/Dinomite07/drzynm96/75/

Comment: When i looked through your code, there were many issues. This is why i provided you with a **minimal working example**. I recommend that you start from there and add on your functionality. If you insist on debugging your code the best way to do this is via the browser. You can type 'debugger' in your code to set breakpoints. For more on this - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/